# CSS vertically-aligned text not working on website?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to vertically center text inside a div for one or more lines. But for some reason this won't work:

```
#image {
    height: 96px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 96px;
}
    #image h5 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 13px;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it to work for a varying number of lines, you need a dynamic solution. Try the `table`/`table-cell` approach:

```
#banner_middle {
    height: 96px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: table;
}
#banner_middle h5 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

No need for using hardcoded `line-height` values.

Comment: @user3420034 I did refer to the JSFiddle. Try the code I posted. I tested it in the Chrome dev tool. It worked.

Comment: @user3420034 The `table`/`table-cell` approach *will* work for multiple lines.